# Ruby on Rails form_with not showing errors, stuck on server side

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm sure I'm just missing something really simple but I'm pretty stumped. I have a user signup form that's properly identifying errors in the signup process on the server, but it's not passing that information back to the views to render the errors above the form.

**controllers/registrations_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)
        if @user.save
            redirect_to root_path, notice: "Successfully signed up!"
        else
            puts 'ERRORS BELOW:'
            puts @user.errors.full_messages
            render :new
        end
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

**views/registrations/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: signup_path do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <div><%= message %></div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class='mb-3'>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class:'form-control', placeholder: 'john@test.com' %>
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3'>
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class:'form-control', placeholder: 'password' %>
    </div>
    <div class='mb-3'>
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class:'form-control', placeholder: 'password' %>
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <%= f.submit 'Get Started', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root to:'main#index'

    get "signup", to: 'registrations#new'
    post "signup", to: 'registrations#create'

    get "about-us", to: 'about#index', as: :about
end
```

**View from my console showing the errors getting printed out serverside**

```
Started POST "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-01-26 10:18:51 -0600
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
    Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"asdfasdg", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Get Started"}
ERRORS BELOW:
Password confirmation doesn't match Password
Email Must be a valid email address
    Rendering layout layouts/application.html.erb
    Rendering registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application
    Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.8ms | Allocations: 2734)
    Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 134)
    Rendered shared/_flash.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 33)
    Rendered layout layouts/application.html.erb (Duration: 54.5ms | Allocations: 17541)
Completed 200 OK in 423ms (Views: 56.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms | Allocations: 22605)
```

I've tried passing them in as a flash notice, as well as not even rendering `:new` after `@user.save` fails, not sure what else to try. A lot of solutions to similar problems I've found on here seem to have been solved by putting the `if`/`else` block in the create function, but I already have that in. Not sure what I'm missing.

I should also add that I am able to create a `User` when I enter in a proper email and matching passwords, and it does not create a user when I fail those two checks, it just doesn't pass those errors back to the client

Comment: oof, well thanks for taking a look!

Comment: `render "new", status: :unprocessable_entity` https://stackoverflow.com/a/71762032/207090

Comment: Thanks @Alex, that solution also worked, and appreciate the citation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
```

Probably that's the problem, but you can disable turbo

Just add `data-turbo="false"` attribute to this form

```
<%= form_with model: @user, url: signup_path, data: { turbo: false } do |f| %>
```

In this case it will be usual HTTP request